# How to get the loaded image path in flex?

Tags: image, apache-flex, path

hi i want to get the loaded image path location,how to get the path?anybody kindly help me

```
<mx:Image source="@Embed('assets/image001.png')" x="240" y="41" width="148" height="118" id="img"/>
```

i need to get this address `source="@Embed('assets/image001.png')"` how?

Comment: Why? You can't access this file directly anyway (without AIR capabilities.) For compiled SWF, this path makes no sense - resource is embedded into it.

Comment: @alxx i need to get the image loaded path how to get this?

Comment: Embedded resources are like source code, just non-textual. Program doesn't know its source code path. You just get your image, that's all. If you need attributes, you can give them names: `name='image1'`.

Comment: ok then how to get the image source path?

Comment: You listening? No way to get source path. Find other way to label your images. You can type source string in the `name` attribute and show it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use

```
img.source
```

in ActionScript to get that source.  I'm unclear if it will give you the text of the path or some binary object of the image, though.   The text would not be very useful, but you should be able to do processing on the bit map data if you needed to.

Comment: I need the image path location,because i have lot of images in my gallery for identification i want to get the image Name.can you explain me with code  in detail,

Comment: Just tested - for embedded resources `source` gives undefined.